# Non-optional expression of type uitextfield used in a check for optionals

Tags: swift, swift3

I am doing an UIAlertController and I got this message:
"Non-optional expression of type uitextfield used in a check for optionals".
This is in the line where I have the "if let my field".

I got this code:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Adding", message: "Type something", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
let DestructiveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in

if let field : UITextField = (alertController.textFields? [0])! as UITextField  {

 if field.text != "" {
//my actions                
        }

    }
    let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    }
    alertController.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "Type designation here"

    }
    alertController.addAction(okAction)
    alertController.addAction(DestructiveAction)
    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Can anyone tell me how to remove this warning please?
I tried to remove the "!" with no success.

Comment: You must not check if the text field exists, since it isn't an optional. You can use this: `let field = alertController.textFields.first!` and than you can perform your actions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are forced unwrapping the value so it's a non-optional. That's what the message tells you.

Since you have definitely added the text field to the alert controller you don't need any check and the code can be shortened:

```
let field  = alertController.textFields![0] // or textFields.first!
```

No type annotation, no type casting, the compiler can infer the type.

To check for empty string there is also a more convenient syntax:

```
if !field.text.isEmpty { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do the cast, the type of `alertController.textFields` is already `[UITextField]`. Adding the cast is what's really causing you the problem.

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Adding", message: "Type something", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
let DestructiveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    if let field : UITextField = alertController.textFields?[0]  {
        if field.text != "" {
            //my actions
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to show you something more. You don't need to set the type and I try to make my conditionals as specific as possible.

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Adding", message: "Type something", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
let DestructiveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    if let text = alertController.textFields?[0].text, !text.isEmpty {
        //my actions
    }
}
```

In addition, I think I would use a guard here.

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Adding", message: "Type something", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
let DestructiveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (result : UIAlertAction) -> Void in
    guard let text = alertController.textFields?[0].text, !text.isEmpty else {
        return
    }

    //my actions
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing `(alertController.textFields? [0])! as UITextField`, don't really make sense, because it means that you are trying to cast `alertController.textFields[0]` to a `UITextField`, when it is already a type of `UITextField`.

What you should do instead is to check if the first element of `alertController.textFields` exist, which you can do so with the code below.

```
if let field : UITextField = alertController.textFields.first  {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Why checking? The text field is clearly created a few lines later.

Comment: @vadian because `alertController.textFields.first` is an optional, and we need to unwrap it. Or you can make the assumption that it is always going to exist by implicitly unwraping it `alertController.textFields.first!`

Comment: You don't need to make an assumption, you definitely **know** it.